I am getting 404 not found, what can I do?
I'm writing web-site on flask and I have a function to delete tournament, this how I call function in html:
<form action="/delete_tournament/{{ tournament['tournament_id'] }}" method="post" style="margin-top: 10px;">
     <input id="guest-button" type="button" name="answer" value="delete tournament" style="background: darkslateblue; border-color: white;">
</form>

And here is the function:
@app.route('/delete_tournament/<int:tournament_id>', methods=["POST", "GET"])
@login_required
def delete_tournament(tournament_id):
    db_sess = db_session.create_session()
    tournament = db_sess.query(Tournament).filter(Tournament.id == tournament_id).first()
    if tournament:
        db_sess.delete(tournament)
        if tournament_id in current_user.tournament_list:
            current_user.delete_tournament(tournament_id)
        for proposal in db_sess.query(Proposal).filter(Proposal.tournament_id == tournament_id).all():
            for participant_id in proposal.participants_list:
                participant = get_participant(participant_id)
                db_sess.delete(participant)
            user = db_sess.query(User).filter(User.id == proposal.team_id).first()
            user.delete_proposal(proposal.id)
            db_sess.delete(proposal)
        db_sess.commit()
    else:
        abort(404)
    return redirect('/')

I have tried to google it actually and didn't find something similar like an solution for my problem, also tried to ask gpt, but there is nothing working

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.


I'd suggest to use url_for function to resolve the path from template files.
In your code you're aborting the request with 404 status if the tournament does not exist in a database. Are you sure it exists?

